# How to access controls, which are in the ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my WP8 appliciation's App.xaml file I've defined ControlTemplate as following:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Name="AddReminderDialog">
            <Canvas  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Height="320" Width="260"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="White" Margin="110,178,110,238">
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="Напомнить" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="92" Canvas.Top="38" />
                <Button Name="btn1HourBef" BorderThickness="0" Click="NotificationButtonClick" Background="Black" Content="За час" Width="260" FontSize="15" Height="60" Margin="0,70,0,0"/>
                <Button Name="btn30MinBef" BorderThickness="0" Click="NotificationButtonClick" Background="Black" Content="За 30 минут" Width="260" FontSize="15" Height="60" Margin="0,130,0,0"/>
                <Button Name="btnOnArrDept" BorderThickness="0" Click="NotificationButtonClick" Background="Black" Content="По прилету/вылету" Width="260" FontSize="15" Height="60" Margin="0,190,0,0"/>
                <Button Name="btnCancel" BorderThickness="0" Click="NotificationButtonClick" Background="Black" Content="Отменить" Width="260" FontSize="15" Height="60" Margin="0, 250, 0, 0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </Canvas>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

I use it as a template of popup as following

```
private void Image_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var image = sender as Image; //get the sender iamge
    var modelItem = image.DataContext; //get image's data context

    const double width = 260;
    const double height = 280;

    //get the flight id from image's tag property(which was binded in flightInfoDataTemplate)
    flightID = Convert.ToString(image.Tag);

    //define content for popup
    var content = new ContentControl()
    {
        Width = width,
        Height = height,
        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent)
    };

    //set the template of content to the contentTemplate, which was defined in app.xaml
    content.Template = (ControlTemplate)Resources["AddReminderDialog"];


    //set popup's datacontext to the image's datacontext
    content.DataContext = modelItem;

    //popup's child property is setting to our content
    popup.Child = content;

    popup.Height = height;
    popup.Width = width;
    popup.VerticalOffset = Application.Current.RootVisual.RenderSize.Height / 2 - height / 2;
    popup.HorizontalOffset = Application.Current.RootVisual.RenderSize.Width / 2 - width / 2;
    popup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

I use this popup to set notification. When user taps the image in the first time the btnCancel button should be invisible, because there is nothing to cancel. When the image is tapped the second time, btnCancel should become visible to cancel the notification. 
I've set button visibility to collapsed by default. But I have not idea how to access that button in the code behind to make it visible.
So my question is how can I change button's visibility settings in the code behind?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
   private void SearchElement(DependencyObject targeted_control) 
      {           
      var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(targeted_control);   // targeted_control is the Canvas  
      if (count > 0)
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
          {
          var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(targeted_control, i);
          if (child is Button ) // specific button control 
            {
             // do your logic
            }
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Will it work before I changed popup's visibility to visible? I have to change button's visibility before the popup is shown to the user

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @BenjaminPaul  I've tried that method with my popup, I mean I've sent my popup as a parameter to that method and checked the count. Count was equal to 0. So it isn't working. <br/> My canvas is in the controlTemplate, which is in the application resources. So I can't send my canvas to that method, that's why I've sent my popup.